# Angularjs ui-select multiple ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, ui-select2

I have an issue with ui-select multiple in AngularJs. The thing is that I can't properly filter a list with ng-repeat.
I have a list of musical instruments, a list of countries and a search input matching a company.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="filter-container pull-left">

      <div>

        <span>Instrument</span>

        <div class="form-group">
          <ui-select class="input-search" multiple ng-model="instrument.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" close-on-select="false" title="Select instruments">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select instruments...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="instrument.value as instrument in instruments | filter: $select.search">
              {{instrument.name}}
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>

        <span>Country</span>

        <div class="form-group">
          <ui-select class="input-search" multiple ng-model="country.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" close-on-select="false" title="Select countries">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select countries...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="country.code as country in countries | filter: $select.search">
              {{country.name}}
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>

        <span>Company</span> 
        <div class="form-group mbl">
          <label for="company" class="sr-only">Company</label>
          <input id="company" ng-model="company.selected" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>            
    </div>


      <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->

      <div style="width:75%; float:right;">

        <div class="results-container">
          <span><strong class="text-info">{{auditions.length}}</strong> auditions</span>
        </div>

        <ul class="ul-nostyle">
          <li ng-repeat="audition in auditions">
            <div>            
              <div class="pull-left">
                <span class="label label-info">{{audition.instrument}}</span> <span class="label label-info"><img src="img/flags/{{audition.country}}.gif" class="flag">{{audition.country}}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-social-facebook">
                  <span class="fui-facebook"></span> 500
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-social-facebook">
                  <span class="fui-user"></span> 500
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="pull-left">
                <small><strong>Closing date:</strong> {{audition.closingDate}}</small>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div>
              <p><strong>{{audition.company}}</strong></p>
              <p class="title"><strong>{{audition.title}}</strong></p>
              <p class="content">{{audition.description}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="{{audition.url}}" class="btn btn-link">More information</a>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>                  
            </div>
          </li>
```

And my model (I don't include all countries...):

```
    //Auditions array
 $scope.audition = [];
 $scope.auditions = [
    {
        instrument: 'trumpet',
        country: 'ES',
        closingDate: '29/12/2015',
        company: 'Orquesta Nacional de España',
        title: 'Title 1',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tellus turpis, egestas nec ex in, volutpat sagittis dolor. Ut laoreet blandit mauris, congue imperdiet odio gravida a. Vivamus lectus massa, viverra in felis elementum, vestibulum tincidunt tortor.',
        url: 'http://www.google.es'
    },
    {
        instrument: 'trombone',
        country: 'DE',
        closingDate: '29/12/2015',
        company: 'Berlin Philarmonic',
        title: 'Title 2',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tellus turpis, egestas nec ex in, volutpat sagittis dolor. Ut laoreet blandit mauris, congue imperdiet odio gravida a. Vivamus lectus massa, viverra in felis elementum, vestibulum tincidunt tortor.',
        url: 'http://www.google.es'
    },
    {
        instrument: 'violin',
        country: 'US',
        closingDate: '29/12/2015',
        company: 'Alabama Symphony',
        title: 'Title 3',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tellus turpis, egestas nec ex in, volutpat sagittis dolor. Ut laoreet blandit mauris, congue imperdiet odio gravida a. Vivamus lectus massa, viverra in felis elementum, vestibulum tincidunt tortor.',
        url: 'http://www.google.es'
    }];

//Instruments array
  $scope.instrument = [];
  $scope.instruments = [
    {name: 'Violin',value: 'violin'},
    {name: 'Viola',value: 'viola'},
    {name: 'Cello',value: 'cello'},
    {name: 'Double-Bass',value: 'doubleBass'},
    {name: 'Flute',value: 'flute'},
    {name: 'Oboe',value: 'oboe'},
    {name: 'Clarinet',value: 'clarinet'},
    {name: 'Bassoon',value: 'bassoon'},
    {name: 'Saxophone',value: 'saxophone'},
    {name: 'French Horn',value: 'frenchHorn'},
    {name: 'Trumpet',value: 'trumpet'},
    {name: 'Trombone',value: 'trombone'},
    {name: 'Tuba/Euphonium',value: 'tubaEuphonium'},
    {name: 'Timpani/Percussion',value: 'timpaniPercussion'},
    {name: 'Harp',value: 'harp'},
    {name: 'Guitar',value: 'guitar'},
    {name: 'Piano',value: 'piano'},
    {name: 'Organ',value: 'organ'},
    {name: 'Harpsichord',value: 'harpsichord'}
  ];

  //Country arrays
  $scope.country = [];
  $scope.countries = [ // Taken from https://gist.github.com/unceus/6501985
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'},
    {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
    {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
    {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
    {name: 'Andorra', code: 'AD'},
    {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},
    {name: 'Anguilla', code: 'AI'},
    {name: 'Antarctica', code: 'AQ'},
    {name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
    {name: 'Argentina', code: 'AR'},
    {name: 'Armenia', code: 'AM'},
    {name: 'Aruba', code: 'AW'},
    {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
    {name: 'Austria', code: 'AT'},
    {name: 'Azerbaijan', code: 'AZ'},
    {name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
    {name: 'Bahrain', code: 'BH'},
    {name: 'Bangladesh', code: 'BD'},
    {name: 'Barbados', code: 'BB'},
    {name: 'Belarus', code: 'BY'},
    {name: 'Belgium', code: 'BE'}
    ...
    ];
```

If anyone can help me please...and sorry for my english :(

Comment: "I can't properly filter a list with ng-repeat". What is the issue?

Comment: I want to show only the results of selecting some instruments, some countries and a search input for companies in a list (the list of auditions) but I don't know how to implement this filter in the ng-repeat list. Thanks!